# vector animation for web library

Tags: animation, web

just wondering around google and could not find a really convincing method (yet) to make an animation web page using my own vector image. I really love to draw and would like my self to go deeper and making an interactive web page (flashless) using my own vector drawing. 
I am already have a good understanding about javascript, html and css so if any of you could suggest a mature and well documented library to use as a base for my project that would be awesome.

Maybe a little pro cons insight using javascript vs css for web animation will also be good for other newbie like me in the future as a consideration before I dip my toe to the sea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric.js seems to encompass many modern features of browsers using the canvas. Check it out, I know it supports SVG.

http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: That look really nice. I will try it :-)